# Erro Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Tags: sql, servidor, instalador

Toda vez que tento iniciar o Management Studio da este erro:

Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.

Já desinstalei o SQL Server e o Management Studio e reinstalei.
Também já instalei o Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell Isolated mas o problema continua.

Alguem tem alguma outra solução?

Comment: Já tentou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807502/sql-server-management-studio-17-cannot-find-one-or-more-components?

Comment: já testei isso sim

Comment: Pois é, depois da instalação da ultima versão do SSMS 17 algumas formatações de sql ficaram estranhas. Estou esperando uma nova atualização para ver se corrige.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas vc esta usando algum outro programa enquanto nao sai a atualizaçao?

Comment: Estou usando ele mesmo, não me atrapalha muito não ter algumas formatações do sql, mas fica estranho.

Comment: o meu aqui nem abre mais @PabloTondolodeVargas